# Python convert decimal number in a string without "."

Tags: python, string, formatting, tuples

I have a tuple of two numbers,

for example: `data = (0.25, 0.25)`

I wish to convert this to a string like this:

```
025and025
```

without the ".".

Comment: What kinds of input do you need this to work with? Arbitrary floating point values of any precision?

Comment: yes Arbitrary floating point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [55]: data = (0.25, 0.25)

In [56]: 'and'.join([str(item).replace('.','') for item in data])
Out[56]: '025and025'
```